# UI Router Prefix

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

For example you site is hosted on "http://www.domain.com". And you have a products page defined by the url below:

```
http://www.domain.com/products
```

Is it possible to define a prefix? Moreover, I want the prefix to have a parameter as well. I would define the products page for different shops using the urls below, where "shop/x" is the prefix with the parameter "x":

```
http://www.domain.com/shop/1/products

http://www.domain.com/shop/2/products/1
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use a .state config along the following lines

```
.config(function($stateProvider) {
    return $stateProvider.state('main', {
      url: '/shop/:shopID/products/:productID',
      ...
    });
```

and then in your controller you can refer to `$scope.shopID` and `$scope.productID` just as you would expect to.